# Google chart, как вывести форматирование данные по оси

Tags: javascript, yii2, google-chart

Я строю график(yii2), в которых выводу по вертикали количество, а по горизонтали дату.
Массив данных у меня подобного типа:

```
[0] => Array ( 
    [0] => Date 
    [1] => Players 
    ) 
[1] => Array ( 
    [0] => Jan 04, 2016 
    [1] => 668197 ) 
[2] => Array ( 
    [0] => Jan 11, 2016 
    [1] => 656406 )
```

И по горизонтали, в подписи у меня выводится Jan 04, 2016, Jan 11, 2016, а мне нужно вывести только год.
Каким образом можно отформатировать дату?
Пробовал так:

```
hAxis: {
  format: 'yyyy'
}
```

не вышло.

Comment: ну так когда формируете массив, переводите дату сразу в нужный вам формат

Comment: Если я при форматировании изменю дату, то на толтипах в графике, так же будет просто год. А мне нужно что бы в толтипах(подсказках к графику) была верная дата, в формате m d, Y. А в подписях по осям только год.

Comment: {format:'y'} тоже не срабатывает ? если нет, то передавайте timestamp в массиве и в самом графике уже форматируйте как надо